# String format with escaping characters

Tags: c#, string, format, escaping

Thanks a lot for reading my thread. I have a command line which I'd like to format as a string in C#. Here is how the string looks in command line prompt:

[image]

**I think I only need to know the format starting from `run.......`, I guess I can handle `fiji -eval`**. **So this is what I am not su to format:**
[image]

In case you cannot see it clearly, I re-type the string here:

```
run("'Bio-Formats Importer'", "'open=[D:\\fiji\\ChanA_0001_0001_0001_0001.tif] display_ome-xml'")
```

The thing confuses me is the '' inside the "", which I am not confident. Anyone has any idea how to format this command line? Thanks a lot!

A little more edit to extend it to dynamic:

```
string fileName = string.Empty;
string[] filesList = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.tif");
fileName = filesList[0];

string bioformats = "Bio-Formats Importer";

options = string.Format("open=[{0}] display_ome-xml", fileName);
runCommand = string.Format("run(\"'{0}'\",\"'{1}'\")", bioformats, options);

 string fijiCmdText = string.Format("/C \"\"{0}\" -eval {1}", fijiExeFile, runCommand);

 try
{
      System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
     System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new              System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
       startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
      startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";

       startInfo.Arguments = fijiCmdText;
       process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        //    _processOn = true;
        process.WaitForExit();

        ret = 1;
     }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          ex.ToString();
           ret = 0;
     }
```

Comment: Not sure if I need glasses, but I can't read that screenshot at all. How about pasting the text here instead?

Comment: OK. 2 minutes. I noticed, but I want to show the original version. Hold on.

Comment: Sorry about it. I have re-typed the string as code. Let me know if you cannot see it still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a normal string literal, but you'd have to escape the the quotes with `\"` and backslashes with `\\`, like this:

```
var str = "run(\"'Bio-Formats Importer'\",\"'open=[D:\\\\fiji\\\\ChanA_0001_0001_0001_0001.tif] display_ome-xml'\")";
```

Or by using a verbatim string literal, but you need to escape the quotes with `""`, like this:

```
var str = @"run(""'Bio-Formats Importer'"",""'open=[D:\\fiji\\ChanA_0001_0001_0001_0001.tif] display_ome-xml'"")";
```

**Further Reading**

- [string (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx)
- [2.4.4.5 String literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

---

Regarding your update, it seems like the problem is that you need to double the slashes in the file path for the benefit of the command line string. I would also recommend simplifying it to something like this:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

var filesList = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.tif");
var bioformats = "Bio-Formats Importer";
foreach(var fileName in filesList)  // loop through every file
{
    var options = string.Format("open=[{0}] display_ome-xml", fileName.Replace("\\", "\\\\"));
    var args = string.Format("-eval run(\"'{0}'\",\"'{1}'\")", bioformats, options);
    try
    {
        var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                FileName = fijiExeFile,
                Arguments = args,
            }
        };
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();

        ret = 1;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
        ret = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to combine the answer together, to do it more dynamically, making the command line accept different files.

Comment: @Ono can you expand on what exactly you're trying to accomplish? What parts of this string will dynamic?

Comment: See edit in original thread. the string is a command consists of several parts. It is escape many times. The input fileName is the dynamic variable.

Comment: My current version is not working because the path needs to be \\\\ in stead of \\

Comment: Seems I need a anti-escaping to add an \\ on the file path.

Comment: @Ono Correct, I had come to the same conclusion, but I thought I'd offer some general pointers on cleaning up the script. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

To escape, use `\`. For example, `"run(\"'Bio-Formats Importer'\""`. For the `\` characters, use `\\`, or in your case `\\\\`.

You can also use `string.Format()` to parameterize this: `string.Format("run(\"'{0}'\", ...", arg0);`

Comment: what is the arg0 here exactly? string arg0 = "Bio-Formats Importer"?

Comment: @Ono Exactly. Your question was a bit unclear as to how you wanted to use this. I'm suggesting `string.Format()` would allow you to nail down the format of the command, but pass in the various arguments dynamically.

Comment: I can get the string.Format("run(\"'{0}'\")", arg0) work, but I cannot get string.Format("run(\"'{0}'\", \"'{1}'\")", arg0, arg1) work.